# How to use Query Function in Google Sheets to pull data from a list within a date range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a long list of information that I want to split into month to month sheets. I tried the Filter Function, The Match+Index Function and the Countif function and the error I kept getting said that the formula had more arguments than expected.

Eventually I settled on using Query, and I think I've got the formula roughly right, but I've been trying to troubleshoot this error and I'm completely stuck.

Here is the formula:

```
=QUERY(Index!1:1988, " SELECT D WHERE (D => date ‘2020,9,1’ and D =< date ‘2020,9,30’)")
```

And this is the error I keep getting:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "D "" at line 1, column 18. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ... "(" ... "(" ...

Comment: Greater than or equal is `>=` and smaller is `<=` in my environment. If I use `=>` the Error is like yours.

Comment: Swapping them to the same as yours still causes the error. Are there any other errors in my formula?

Comment: This works for my sheet: `=QUERY(A1:A1000, " SELECT A WHERE A >= date '1970-09-01' AND A <= date '1970-09-02'")`.

Comment: That you, It is no longer giving me an error message, However it just says "Date Created" in the cell with the formula. What I am wanting it to do is copy the rows within those dates into the new sheet.

Comment: You've probably copied my formula. Yours should look like this: ``=QUERY(Index!1:1988, " SELECT D WHERE D >= date '2020-09-01' AND D <= date '2020-09-30'")``.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(Index!D:D, "where D >= date '2020-09-01' and D <= date '2020-09-30'", 0)
```